# GNU/Linux: how to detect hard disk mappings?

Tags: linux, debian, hard-disk, devices

Let's suppose you have two hard-disks:

- one internal (boots GNU/Linux (Debian));
- one external (USB).

`fdisk -l` detects both, but will not tell you which is `/dev/sda` and which is `/dev/sdb`. `lsusb` will tell you there is an external USB device connected, but will not tell you whether it has been mapped to `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`.

How can you be get such information from your system?

Comment: See also [How to know if /dev/sdX is a connected USB or HDD?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40143)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls -l /sys/class/block/sd?
```

The `sd?` entries are symbolic links that show how the disk is connected to the computer. There'll be a `/usb` in there for a USB disk.

```
udevadm info -a -n sda
```

This shows all the identifying information the kernel can get at directly for `sda`. You'll see how the disk is connected in more detail, e.g. going directly from `SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"` to `SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", DRIVERS=="ahci"` for a SATA disk on an Intel controller, or going from `SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"` to `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb-storage"` for an USB disk.

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-*
```

Under `/dev/disk/by-*`, you can locate disks by hardware attachment (`by-path`), by some globally unique identifier (`by-uuid`), by human-chosen label (`by-label`), or by manufacturer identification (`by-id`).

Comment: "ls -l /sys/class/block/sd?" is what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

On my Debian box (now on Lubuntu), I often used to use `testdisk -l` *(read: 'minus small L')* for this purpose. I am aware that not every distro has `testdisk` (a well-known recovery tool) pre-installed, but most ought to have it.

Another great tool which I learned not long ago is `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk -d -io KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL
```

or, if you only want your HDDs to show:

```
$ lsblk -d -io KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL | grep 'sd\w'
```

*(The \w, albeit not mandatory, will avoid ugly "half-colored" output on distros that in default configuration have `grep` aliased to `grep --color=auto`.)*

You may also use my (in reality very complex) script which I've decided to trim down to serve only this one little purpose:

https://serverfault.com/questions/64219/how-to-know-which-block-device-maps-to-which-physical-drive/548795#548795

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of the best answer, but here are some ideas:

You can look at `/sys/class/block/sdX/device/model` to get the make/model information reported by the device.  For example:

```
cat /sys/class/block/sda/device/model 
SAMSUNG HD161GJ
```

This by itself might be enough to identify which one is your external and which one is your internal device.  You can look at the output from `dmesg`, which for USB devices will include something like:

```
[ 2073.412999] scsi12 : usb-storage 2-1.8:1.0
```

This identifies identifies SCSI bus 12 as a USB storage bus.  We can then look for SCSI devices on bus 12:

```
# dmesg | grep scsi12
[ 2074.488651] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[ 2076.592154] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] 30481152 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
[ 2076.592639] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[ 2076.592645] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 2076.593142] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[ 2076.593147] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2076.596270] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[ 2076.596276] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2076.619078] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page present
[ 2076.619084] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2076.619088] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 3):

Often the quickest is just to cat `/proc/scsi/scsi`, which will have enough to show you which is which:

```
$ cat /proc/scsi/scsi 
Attached devices:
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: ST95005620AS     Rev: SD23
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi4 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: 2.0      Model: USB Flash Drive  Rev: 1.00
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 02
```

So, in my case, the first (which would be sda) is a Seagate ST95005620AS, and the second (sdb) is a USB Flash Drive.

To get more detailed and specific info, look in `/sys/block/sda` and `/sys/block/sdb`, and also `/sys/class/scsi_disk`.

`/sys/class/scsi_disk` in particular contains symlinks into the PCI address tree which will reveal USB vs SATA hosts:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/scsi_disk
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-28 23:50 2:0:0:0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/scsi_disk/2:0:0:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-28 23:50 4:0:0:0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0
$ cat /sys/block/sd[ab]/device/model
ST95005620AS    
USB Flash Drive
```

For more info, try also, `find /sys -name 'scsi*'` and `find /sys/block/sd[a-z]/`.

Answer (score 2):

Gilles' answer I think is the best, but I'm adding this one just for the sake of completeness.

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda
```

This will show you some basic info the controller driver obtained from the drive (including model and serial number). This command does not require root if you have read access to the `/dev` device (like via group permissions).

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

This will show you a ton of advanced information about the drive (model, serial number, and everything possible). This command does require root.

Answer (score 1):

The two commands that I normally use in situations like this are `lsblk` and `blkid`. The former will output each disk block device with a list of partitions, their size, and their mountpoint (if mounted) (and maybe their volume labels, if present, although I haven't got any devices with volume labels connected at the moment to check this with). The latter will output each partition with its filesystem type, UUID, and volume label (if present).

`mount` will also tell you where each device is mounted, so the device mounted at the filesystem root is the boot device. I believe internal hard drives are also enumerated before external hard drives, so `/dev/sda` should be the internal hard drive.