# How to know if /dev/sdX is a connected USB or HDD?

Tags: bash, hardware, hard-disk, administration

How can I know if `/dev/sdX` is a local HDD or USB key? 
I’d prefer a way of doing this without root privileges.

OK, `udevadm` helped a lot:

For local HDD:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=sdb | grep ID_BUS
E: ID_BUS=ata
```

For USB key:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=sdc | grep ID_BUS
E: ID_BUS=usb
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/361885/how-do-i-figure-out-which-dev-is-a-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a few ways to tell without root privileges, many of them tricky/hacky:

Using `/dev/disk/by-id`:

```
find /dev/disk/by-id/ -lname '*sdX'
```

If this responds with something like `/dev/disk/by-id/usb-blah-blah-blah`, then it's a USB disk. Other prefixes include `ata`, `dm`, `memstick`, `scsi`, etc.

Using `/dev/disk/by-path` isn't significantly different:

```
find /dev/disk/by-path/ -lname '*sdX'
```

You'll get something like `/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0`. This shows the device path leading to the disk. In this case, a rough path is PCI → USB → disk. (note the `-usb-`).

Using udev (I run Debian. My `udevadm` is in `/sbin` which isn't on my `$PATH` — yours might be elsewhere, on or off your `$PATH`):

```
/sbin/udevadm info --query=all --name=sdX | grep ID_BUS
```

You'll get the bus type the device is on. Remove the `| grep ID_BUS` for the complete listing of information (you may need to add `|less`).

If you have `lshw` installed, Huygens' answer *may* also work:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage | less
```

And look through the output for your disk. In `less`, try <kbd>/</kbd> sdX and look at the preceding, `bus info` lines — the first one will just say `scsi@…`, but the one several lines before it will be more enlightening. However, you really *should* run this as the superuser so it may not be suitable. (symptoms: on the laptop I tried it, it listed the SATA disk but not the USB one — running with `sudo` listed both)

There are other ones too, more or less direct than these ones.

Comment: Are there ways to tell apart an internal SATA drive versus an external SATA drive connected over `esatap`?

Answer (score 17):

You could use `lsblk` to report `TRAN`  (device transport type)
:

`lsblk -do name,tran`

```
NAME TRAN
sda  sata
sdb  sata
sdd  usb
```

where `-d`or `--nodeps` means don't print slaves and `-o name,tran` or `--output name,tran` means list only name of device and device transport type. Add `rm` to the list of output columns to see which devices are removable (`1` if `true`):

`lsblk --nodeps --output NAME,TRAN,RM`

```
NAME TRAN   RM
sda  sata    0
sdb  sata    0
sdd  usb     1
```

or `-n` to remove headers, e.g. to print only the transport type for a certain drive:

`lsblk -ndo tran /dev/sdb`

```
sata
```

Note that modern versions of `lsblk` (`2.27` and newer) support `JSON` output so you could also do something like:

`lsblk -Jdo name,tran | jq -r '.blockdevices[] | select(.tran=="usb") | .name'`

to list only block devices connected on the `USB` bus.

Comment: I was looking for this in the answers

Comment: this is by far the best solution, and can be easily used inside script.

Comment: with -n to remove headers and it's perfect :)

Answer (score 10):

I know a solution, but, sadly, it requires root privilege. 
Anyway, you might still find it useful:

```
sudo lshw -class disk -class storage
```

For each device it will print the logical name (e.g., `/dev/sda`) and bus info, which in case of a USB device would be something like 'usb@1:2'.

Sample output:

```
[...]
  *-storage
       description: SATA controller
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
[...]
     *-disk:0
          description: ATA Disk
          physical id: 0
          bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
[...]
  *-scsi
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:2
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sdc
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't need root privileges
(but many of these commands use and depend on bashisms,
so they will not work in all POSIX-compliant shells):

There is a quick way to ask about a `sdX`:

```
grep -H . /sys/block/sda/{capability,uevent,removable,device/{model,type,vendor,uevent}}
/sys/block/sda/capability:52
/sys/block/sda/uevent:MAJOR=8
/sys/block/sda/uevent:MINOR=0
/sys/block/sda/uevent:DEVNAME=sda
/sys/block/sda/uevent:DEVTYPE=disk
/sys/block/sda/removable:0
/sys/block/sda/device/model:WDC WD360GD-00FN
/sys/block/sda/device/type:0
/sys/block/sda/device/vendor:ATA     
/sys/block/sda/device/uevent:DEVTYPE=scsi_device
/sys/block/sda/device/uevent:DRIVER=sd
/sys/block/sda/device/uevent:MODALIAS=scsi:t-0x00
```

The *really* interesting file is `capability`. On my Debian, I have a `genhd.h` file, so:

```
eval $(sed -ne '
   s/#define.*GENHD_FL_\([A-Z0-9_]*\)[ \t]*\([0-9]*\) \?.*$/GENHD_FLAGS[\2]="\1"/p
  ' /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common-openvz/include/linux/genhd.h)
diskCapa=$(</sys/block/sda/capability)
for i in ${!GENHD_FLAGS[@]};do
    (( diskCapa & i )) && echo ${GENHD_FLAGS[i]}
  done
MEDIA_CHANGE_NOTIFY
UP
SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO

diskCapa=$(</sys/block/sdd/capability)
    for i in ${!GENHD_FLAGS[@]};do
    (( diskCapa & i )) && echo ${GENHD_FLAGS[i]}
  done
REMOVABLE
MEDIA_CHANGE_NOTIFY
UP
SUPPRESS_PARTITION_INFO
```

At all, for only knowing if flag `removable` is set:

```
grep REMOVABL /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/genhd.h 
#define GENHD_FL_REMOVABLE                      1
```

so

```
for disk in sd{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} ; do
 (( $(< /sys/block/$disk/capability ) & 1 ))  &&  echo $disk is removable
done
```

works by testing whether the `capability` value
(which is 52 in my `sda` example, above)
has the `1` bit set (i.e., whether it is an odd number).

But Linux renders all flags in `/sys`, so asking for `/sys/block/sdX/removable` is a lot simpler! ;-)

So a USB key could be `removable`, but as there are lots of *removable* devices, I would prefer to ensure that the *size* of the medium is greater than 0 (like an unloaded CD-ROM tray, for sample)
**and** that the *device* is **not** in use: In watching that `sdX/trace/enable` is not binded:

Nota: All this is well tested on bash v4.2+.

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use this very quick and efficient way:

```
for disk in /sys/block/* ; do
    [ -f "$disk/removable" ]    && [ $(<"$disk/removable") -gt 0 ]   &&
    [ -f "$disk/size" ]         && [ $(<"$disk/size") -gt 0 ]        &&
    [ -f "$disk/trace/enable" ] && [ -z "$(<"$disk/trace/enable")" ] &&
    echo "${disk##*/} $(($(<"$disk/size")/1953125))G $(<"$disk/device/model")"
  done
```

On my system, there are 4 USB keys, but one of them (`sde`) is already mounted, so the previous command output:

```
sdd 8G Trans-It Drive
sdf 7G Storage Media
sdg 4G silicon-power
```

**My script:**

There is a little [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function I wrote to install upgraded Debian Live.

```
#!/bin/bash

txtsize() {
    local _c=$1 _i=0 _a=(b K M G T P)
    while [ ${#_c} -gt 3 ] ; do
        ((_i++))
        _c=$((_c>>10))
      done
    _c=000$(( ( $1*1000 ) >> ( 10*_i ) ))
    ((_i+=${3:-0}))
    printf -v ${2:-REPLY} "%.2f%s" ${_c:0:${#_c}-3}.${_c:${#_c}-3} ${_a[_i]}
}
```

# The first part only renders human readable size. The function begins there.

```
chooseFreeUsbKey() {
    local _lUdisk _lUsize _lUdialog=dialog # whiptail # gdialog
    local -A _lUdevices
    unset ${1:-REPLY}
    for _lUdisk in /sys/block/*; do
        [ -f $_lUdisk/removable ] && [ $(<$_lUdisk/removable) -gt 0 ] &&
        [ -f $_lUdisk/size ] && [ $(<$_lUdisk/size) -gt 0 ] &&
        txtsize $(<$_lUdisk/size)*512 _lUsize &&
        [ -f $_lUdisk/trace/enable ] && [ -z "$(<$_lUdisk/trace/enable)" ] &&
        _lUdevices[${_lUdisk##*/}]="$_lUsize $(<$_lUdisk/device/model)"
    done
    case ${#_lUdevices[@]} in
        0 ) ;; # echo Sorry no key found. ;;
        1 ) IFS=§ read -a ${1:-REPLY} \
            <<< "${!_lUdevices[@]}§${_lUdevices[@]%% *}§${_lUdevices[@]#* }";;
        * ) declare -a menu
           for _lUdisk in ${!_lUdevices[@]}; do
               menu+=($_lUdisk "${_lUdevices[$_lUdisk]}")
           done
           _lUdisk=$($_lUdialog --menu "Choose a USB stick" \
               $((LINES-3)) $((COLUMNS-3)) $((LINES-8)) \
               "${menu[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
           IFS=§ read -a ${1:-REPLY} \
           <<< "$_lUdisk§${_lUdevices[$_lUdisk]%% *}§${_lUdevices[$_lUdisk]#* }"
    esac
}
```

This assigns the answer, as an **array**, to the variable given as the first argument or to variable `$REPLY`:

```
chooseFreeUsbKey stick

echo "$stick"
sdf

echo "${stick[1]}"
7.26G

echo "${stick[2]}"
Storage Media
```

(The last field may contain spaces.)

Comment: Thanks to @StephaneChazelas for making the first part of my answer more readable.

Comment: (1) Why do you have nested curly braces?  Do you mean `…,device/{model,type,vendor,uevent}`?  (2) Can you please explain your GENHD commands and your “trace/enable” commands?  (3) Your `[ $(( $(< $file ) & 1 )) -ne 0 ]` test can be simplified (shortened) to `(( $(< $file ) & 1 ))`.

Comment: @G-Man (1) Yes, +1 for this! I don't understand how this tipo was introduced. (2) The *Generic hard disk header* file must be present in `/usr/src/*/include/linux`. Try `sed -ne 's/#define.*GENHD_FL_\([A-Z0-9_]*\)[ \t]*\([0-9]*\) \?.*$/GENHD_FLAGS[\2]="\1"/p;' /usr/src/*/include/linux/genhd.h` . (3) Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Just read value of `/sys/block/sdX/removable`.

For example:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/removable
0
$ cat /sys/block/sdc/removable
1
```

`/dev/sdc` is an USB key (it could be a SD card or any other removable media).

Comment: This duplicates information in [F. Hauri’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40143/80216#60339) and adds no new content.  Please don’t post an answer unless you can add new aspects not found in any existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just using `hdparm` or `lshw` (which you might need to install), and using `sudo` to execute it as root.

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
sudo lshw -short -C disk
sudo lshw -class disk -class storage
```

should all give you information.

Comment: hdparm on a virtual disk: `hdparm -i /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: Well, I said *should* and it works here with virtual disks.

Answer (score 0):

`dmesg` is the easiest method:

```
dmesg | grep sdX
```

(`sdX` being the name of your device, e.g., `sda`)

From the command above, you will see the following:

- Attached SCSI disk (hard disk)
- Attached SCSI removable disk (removable media; such as, USB flash drive)

Comment: `dmesg` reads the kernel's circular message buffer so this solution will only work relatively recently after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below commands to get SD, USB, and SATA device nodes.

```
usb_device="/dev/`ls -lR /dev/disk/by-id/  | grep ^l | grep 'usb' | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d '/' -f 3 | awk 'NR == 1'`"

sata_device="/dev/`ls -lR /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep ^l | grep 'ata' | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d '/' -f 3 | awk 'NR == 1'`"

sd_device="/dev/`ls -lR /dev/disk/by-id/   | grep ^l | grep 'mmc' | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d '/' -f 3 | awk 'NR == 1'`"
```

Comment: (1) It’s not obvious to me how this answers the question, which is, “For any particular `/dev/sdX`, how can I know if it is a local HDD or a USB key?”  Please explain how the OP can use your commands to make that determination.  (2) We prefer answers that give commands *and explain them* over answers that provide only commands.  Please explain what you’re doing.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) `awk` is a very powerful tool. Many beginners post answers that do a `grep` and pipe its output into `awk`. This is rarely necessary; `awk` can do pattern matching and can select the desired input without help from `grep`. You have a pipeline of two `grep` commands, piped into `awk`, and then a *second* `awk` command. This can be greatly simplified; please try. (4) Also, for clarity, you might want to change `\`…\`` to `$(…)` — see [this](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/80216), [this](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838/80216), and [this](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119/80216).

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy, inxi tells me this easily:

```
inxi -D
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1220.3GB (33.2% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST380817AS size: 80.0GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD1003FZEX size: 1000.2GB
           ID-3: USB /dev/sdc model: USB_Flash_Drive size: 140.0GB
```

I believe it also tells me if it's firewire and maybe one other type, but I'd have to double check, haven't used those types in a while.

It also tells me using -p if partitions are remote, like samba or nfs mounts.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can get the complete path of any device from sysfs. No privileges needed.

For each block device there is symlink of the form `major:minor` (in decimal) inside `/sys/dev/block` pointing to the complete path of the device through all the buses. Same for character devices inside `/sys/dev/char`. Here is an example that should also work on devices without bash, stat, util-linux, udev, lshw, hdparm, sudo, perl/python, jq, golang, etc:

```
syspath(){ readlink -f /sys/dev/$(ls -l "$1" | awk -F'[, ]+' '{print ($1~/^c/?"char/":"block/")$5":"$6}'); }

syspath /dev/sda
/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
                                                                             ^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

After you plug in the USB device, run `dmesg` in a console window. You will be provided with some hints.

For example it will says something along the lines of "Device plugged in, mass storage /dev/sdd".

Comment: Please provide more information/clarification to make your answer useful.

Comment: How about not being insulting when answering a question?