# What is a Linux command that lists only USB storage devices?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, scsi

I would like to list only the USB storage devices connected to my computer. Since these are SCSI disks, I used the command `lsscsi`, which lists the USB drives as well as my computer's hard drive and CD drive. Is there a way to ignore the memory storage that's not a USB? I have also tried `lsusb`, but this includes my keyboard, mouse, and other non-storage devices.

Comment: So "I would like to list only the USB devices connected to my computer." is not what you want? Do you want to list only the USB __storage__ devices on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I want just the storage devices. I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: [`lsblk -do name,tran | awk '$2=="usb"{print $1}'`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225105)

Comment: @don_crissti well that's a little gem hidden away in the comments. Any reason why you didn't provide it as an answer? I don't understand StackExchance that well so there could be a good reason.

Comment: @whossname - well, my comment is actually a link... ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168650/how-do-i-list-all-storage-devices-thumb-drives-external-hard-drives-that-are-c) checks the list of all attached block devices and iterates over them with `udevadmin` to check their respective `ID_BUS`.

You can see all attached block devices in `/sys/block`. Here is the bash script from the linked answer that should let you know if it is a USB storage device:

```
for device in /sys/block/*
do
    if udevadm info --query=property --path=$device | grep -q ^ID_BUS=usb
    then
        echo $device
    fi
done
```

Comment: props for the ^ID_BUS=usb I was thinking how to achieve this.

Comment: That part came from the linked answer :) But yeah it is pretty smooth.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a function:

```
dmu() {
  # Criação       : 2019-07-24 RBR.
  local disks=`lsblk -o name,tran | awk '$2=="usb"{print $1}' | tr "\n" " " | sed -E "s/^ +//g;s/ +$//g"`
  local mask=`sed -E "s/ /\([\\\\t ]|[0-9]\)+|/g;s/$/\([\\\\t ]|[0-9]\)+/g" <<< ${disks}`
  lsblk -f | sed -n "1p" 
  lsblk -f | grep -E "$mask"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lsblk --noheadings --nodeps --paths --raw --output NAME,RM,TRAN,TYPE | grep " 1 usb disk$" | cut --delimiter " " --fields 1
```

Example output:

```
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
/dev/sdf
```

Basically, with `grep` you filter removable USB disks. Some examples of unfiltered `lsblk` output for various devices:

- `/dev/loop0 0  loop`
- `/dev/sda 0 sata disk` SATA SSD
- `/dev/sdb 0 sata disk` SATA HDD
- `/dev/sdd 1 usb disk` **USB flash drive**
- `/dev/sr0 1 sata rom` SATA DVD-RW

Answer (score -1):

You can use lsblk.

```
lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   285M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0  74,5G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0 389,1G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Usualy usb devices are on sdb so lsblk sdb should give all usb devices.

Comment: I think this might work. The only thing is that SCSI disks are added in the order that they're mounted and so I'd just have to assume that my hard drive and DVD drive were only sda.